# Unable to publish jest test case report to SonarQube 6.1 and SonarScanner 3.3 through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jestjs, devops, sonarqube-scan

When I am using SonarQube 6.7, I'm able to publish jest unit test cases report to SonarQube successfully through Jenkins. But when I am using SonarQube 6.1, I am not able to publish reports to SonarQube.

Just want to mention that I'm able to generate the report in workspace successfully in lcov format (coverage report) and xml format (for unit test pass-fail report) Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Please find below configurations:

- For SonarQube 6.1, I have mentioned below properties in `sonar-project.properties`:

  ```
  sonar.projectKey=jest-unit-test-demo-project
  sonar.projectName=Plan Sponsor Reports
  sonar.projectVersion=1.0
  sonar.sources=./app/components/Demo/src
  sonar.tests=./app/components/Demo/test
  sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath=./JS_Junit_Report/coverage/lcov.info
  sonar.junit.reportsPath=./JS_Junit_Report/junit/Junit-Jest-Report.xml
  ```
- For SonarQube 6.7.6, I have mentioned below properties in `sonar-project.properties`:

  ```
  sonar.projectKey=jest-unit-test-demo-project
  sonar.projectName=Plan Sponsor Reports
  sonar.projectVersion=4.27.4
  sonar.sources=./app/components/Demo/src
  sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=sonar-reports/lcov.info
  sonar.tests=./app/components/Demo/test
  sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=./sonar-reports.xml
  ```

Comment: Is there any error in the jenkins console logs?

Comment: There is no error in the jenkins console logs but it is saying 0 files analyzed when my lcov.info file mentioned the source file. Below is the logs.

Comment: INFO: 0 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Sensor Embedded CSS Analyzer Sensor (done) | time=73ms
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor
INFO: Sensor SonarJavaXmlFileSensor (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for js
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Calculating CPD for 0 files

Comment: Why do you want to use SonarQube 6.1 (deprecated) if you already use the LTS version?

Comment: Did you try to use the same configuration for both environments? Now you are using different paths, so this could be the reason of the error.

Comment: Now SonarQube 6.1 version is in the production environment so I am bound to use 6.1 version only.

Comment: I have used the same configuration for both environment but still it is not working.